# Downloading Microsoft Flight Smiluator - download blocked from Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, installation

Installing Microsoft Flight Simulator - download gets blocked from Microsoft Store and you may get these errors:

Microsoft Store:
0x803fb107

XBox Beta:
0x80073d28

How do I download it first to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is:

1. Update to latest Windows
2. Disable Windows Firewall
3. Run this PowerShell command (start > type > PowerShell > right click > Run As Admin):

   Get-AppXPackage -allusers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

This will allow you to actually download the 1.16 GB installer from Microsoft Store. This step took 3 attempts. I ended up switching to an Admin Profile to get it finally working.

Launch the installer from an Admin account, don't assume a PowerUser can do it with elevated permissions. You need to be logged in as Admin (there are multiple ServiceHost processes that prompt for Admin rights).

The next trick is either changing your country, disconnecting internet cable for 5 seconds, or registering your PC as the target. This bit takes hours to suss out! There's a point where you realize it's to do with activating your account, log in and out and back in. Register your PC with Microsoft if prompted.

Finally during the actual install if it hangs then follow these instructions:

https://appuals.com/microsoft-flight-simulator-download-and-loading-issues/

Deleting the latest file and restarting the installer works.

Another trick is to run this [cports](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) script during the install (google the code back to the official forum):

```
cd E:\Utils\cports-x64\
:loop
cports.exe /close * * * * 19012
timeout /t 300 > nul

goto loop
```

Save the above code to a txt file, rename the extension to .bat, make sure cports is located in `E:\Utils\cports-x64` or change that path. Then when the MSFS installer gets stuck (the actual game installer not the Microsoft Store download) double click the .bat file.